# I'm receiving an error when I run my app on heroku. It's saying something about no access. Any thoughts?

Tags: heroku, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I've created an app that will pull deals from an api into the app, and display a map on the site showing the users location. It works fine in the browser, but doesn't work when it is deployed to heroku. Here is the error message:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.sqoot.com/v2/deals?api_key=fflt53&location=?07081&action=query.location&list=search&format=json. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value 'null'. Origin 'https://immense-forest-3648.herokuapp.com' is therefore not allowed access.
deal.js:116 Object

Answer (score 0):

Add HTTP header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` or `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://api.sqoot.com/` to response of your application.

Comment: refs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work